# Translating Mips assembly to machine code: BNE

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code

Given this code:

```
[0x00000000]  arraycopy: lw $t0, 0($a0)
[0x00000004]             addi $a0, $a0,4
[0x00000008]             addi $a1, $a1,4
[0x0000000C]             sw $t0, -4($a1)
[0x00000010]             bne $t0,$0,arraycopy
[0x00000014]             Nop ( means no operation )
```

Now I'm interested to translate the `bne` command line to machine code:

**What I got:
0001 0100 0000 1000 - ....**

Now what will be the rest of the command?

**Update: I keep getting that the Offset value is: `1111 1111 1110 1100` which is -20
But the correct answer should be : `0xfffb` which is -5

Any Idea why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MIPS instructions *must* be aligned to 4 byte boundaries, the offset within a branch instruction can be encoded [and *is* encoded] as a *word* offset and *not* a byte offset. This increases the reachable range of the branch by 4x [a good thing]. So, for an signed encoded offset of 16 bits, you get a signed byte offset of 18 bits

Thus, for a given byte offset, it is encoded in the branch by shifting it right by 2 [i.e. the lower two bits *must* always be zero, so nothing gets lost]. When the instruction is executed, the hardware will take the offset and restore it to a byte offset by shifting it left by 2.

The byte offset is calculated *not* from the address of the branch itself (0x00000010) but from the address of the instruction following (0x00000014).

So, the byte offset is -0x00000014 (decimal -20) --> 0xFFFFFFEC. Shifting this right 2 bits [dividing by 4] produces 0xFFFFFFFB (decimal -5).

Since the encoded offset is only a signed 16 bits, we end up with 0xFFFB